# Elasticsearch partial search of words | Angular

Tags: angular, http, elasticsearch

i am working on a search service for an angular project. I can search for usernames and i want to enable partial search, for example Username: "Brown" should be found while searching for "brow". If possible i want to do that with the URL only, without changing too much. http://URL:9200/users/_doc/_search?q=username:'; this is what i used for my GET requests and then added the written text from the search bar to it and got all informations from the database.

Comment: Something stopping you from doing this? Is there a problem you need help with?

Comment: i want to know how to partial search with Elasticsearch with only URL querying

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query string query with a wildcard.

```
curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200/users/doc/_search -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"brow*", "fields":["username"]}}}'
```

Comment: Sorry i am new to Angular & Elastic, but where do i even write this?

Comment: This is elastic GET URL 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/users/doc/_search' and '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"brow*", "fields":["username"]}}}' is request body which is of type "application/json"